# Possible bug on the flag question popup screen

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

I am experiencing a strange issue in the flag question screen. The screen seems to be working right, but if I select the option "this question does not belong here" the screen closes automagically without creating the flag or allowing me to click the "flag" button. All other options *seems" to work (at last no one cause the closure of the screen - I haven't tried creating a fake flag).

Has anyone else noticed it?

Comment: Is this still a problem?

Comment: no - it is fixed now, as per my auto answer below. Would have accepted it before, but you know... 2 day timer. ^_^

Comment: @MarcGravell - you can close this now and set the status completed tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was indeed a bug. And it was fixed.

See the main meta site for the original discussion.